# How to find the Kafka partition being accessed by each Spark Partition along with their offset Range for every microbatch?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I need to track for auditing purposes, the details of every Spark task, like the worker IP where the task ran, duration when it began and completed, what Kafka topic-partition it read and what were the offsets being processed by each task for every microbatch interval?

I am using Kafka Direct streaming approach and I know that I can use the below code

```
OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) consRecordRDD.rdd()).offsetRanges();
```

I am already using that to log my offsets in the event of any failures, from the driver.

What I need to be able to do is to get details of the which Kafka partition each Spark Task was accessing and the offsets it was trying to process for every microbatch.

I am not able to find any Spark Partition/Task Id in the offsetRanges array.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In essence you can access TaskContext in your executor function that can provide you the information of TASK ID, STAGE ID etc.

CODE SAMPLE:

```
public class MyFunction implements VoidFunction<Iterator<String>> {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyFunction .class);

public void call(Iterator<String> iterator) throws Exception {
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

TaskContext tc = TaskContext.get();
    int partitionId = TaskContext.getPartitionId()
    long tid = tc.taskAttemptId();
    int sid = tc.stageId();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        // your processing of each message
     }
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
log.info("HOST="{}" STAGE_ID={} TASK_ID={} PARTITION_ID={} ELAPSE_TIME={}",
                getHostName(), sid, tid, partitionId,(endTime-startTime));
   }
    // you can cache the host name 
    private static String hostName;

    public static String getHostName() {

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(hostName)) {
            try {
                hostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                logger.warn("Error occured while getting hostname through IndetAddress. stack={}", e);
                hostName = System.getenv("hostname");// get it from environment
                }
            }
        return hostName;
    }
  }

}
```

You can also add task completion listener.

```
TaskContext tc = TaskContext.get();
tc.addTaskCompletionListener(new TaskCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTaskCompletion(TaskContext arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long taskId = arg0.taskAttemptId();
        int stageId = arg0.stageId();
    }
});
```